# How to automatically close a python animation after its execution

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

How can we close a python animation after its execution automatically so that the rest of the program can be executed? For example, I have the following code which shows the first animation, but I have to close it manually before the code proceeds to the second animation.

**Updated**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

plt.style.use('classic')


def update(step,arr,axis,max_step):

    print(step,max_step)

    for i in range(5):
        for j in range(5):
            axis[i, j].xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.NullLocator())
            axis[i, j].yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.NullLocator())
            if arr[step][i, j] == 10:
                axis[i, j].imshow(Image.open('A.jpg'), cmap="bone")
            else:
                axis[i, j].imshow(Image.open('B.jpg'), cmap="bone")

    if step>=max_step:
        plt.close()
    return axis

if __name__ == '__main__':

    a = []
    for i in xrange(5):
        temp = np.zeros((5, 5))
        temp[i, i] = 10
        a.append(temp)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(5, 5, figsize=(5, 5))
    fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0, wspace=0)

    # FuncAnimation will call the 'update' function for each frame; here
    # animating over 10 frames, with an interval of 200ms between frames.
    anim = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=5, fargs=(a, ax,4), interval=200, repeat=False)

    plt.show()

    # repeat the above procedure
    a = []
    for i in xrange(5):
        temp = np.zeros((5, 5))
        temp[i, i] = 10
        a.append(temp)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(5, 5, figsize=(5, 5))
    fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0, wspace=0)

    # FuncAnimation will call the 'update' function for each frame; here
    # animating over 10 frames, with an interval of 200ms between frames.
    anim = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=5, fargs=(a, ax,4), interval=200, repeat=False)

    plt.show()
```

Using the suggestion in the comment, the above code actually works but I also get this error:

```
(0, 4)
(0, 4)
(1, 4)
(2, 4)
(3, 4)
(4, 4)
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1536, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 587, in callit
    func(*args)
  File "/Users/asgharis/PycharmProjects/Q_Network/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/_backend_tk.py", line 310, in idle_draw
    self.draw()
  File "/Users/asgharis/PycharmProjects/Q_Network/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 13, in draw
    tkagg.blit(self._tkphoto, self.renderer._renderer, colormode=2)
  File "/Users/asgharis/PycharmProjects/Q_Network/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/tkagg.py", line 34, in blit
    dataptr, colormode, bboxptr)
TclError: this isn't a Tk application
(0, 4)
(0, 4)
(1, 4)
(2, 4)
(3, 4)
(4, 4)
```

Any idea for addressing this error?

Comment: I would say this is pretty much what [running-funcanimation-multiple-times-with-different-parameters-in-a-for-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47666679/running-funcanimation-multiple-times-with-different-parameters-in-a-for-loop) asks for. Can you comment if or in how far it is or is not a solution?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks, it worked but I got an error as well. I updated the question with the error I get. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: It seems like you're closing the animation while it's still running.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Any idea for fixing this?

Comment: I can't run your code (see [mcve]) but as said I suspect you close the figure before the animation stops. The fix would be to only close the animation once the last animation step has happened.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Because of the two images I have, you cannot run my code or there is any other issue? I cannot fix the problem :( can you help me

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Can you tell me what "plt.close(line.axes.figure)" does in the code of the link you provided in the first comment? I replaced it with "plt.cloes()". Maybe that's the issue.

Comment: `plt.close(line.axes.figure)` is the same as `plt.close(fig)` and it closes a particular figure, while `plt.close()` would close the current figure. Since you only have a single figure open at a time here, those should be the same. As said, your problem would be that the animation still runs when you close the figure. Once the figure is closed, the animation tries to animate a closed figure, which is impossible.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest What do you suggest that I should do? Should I create some delay to make sure the animation has finished? I tried this, but I still get the error. Maybe the way I create the delay is not corret

Comment: No this should be done simply by the order of the respective commands. E.g. if you call `plt.close()` and after that `ax.set_whatever` it will simply not work. Also mind which frame is really the last one.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I updated my code. Each animation has 5 frames from 0 to 4. So, the step in the animation changes from 0 to 4. For which value of step, should I close the plot? I printed the step number in my update function and I don't know why it prints step 0 twice. Any idea?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest is there anyway, you can consider one arbitrary image and run my code?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I got the same error when I run the code in your answer to the other post. The source of problem should be something else. Any other idea?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Is it possible that it is because of my backend 'tkagg'? Because that's what the error says. It is more like a warning, as the code works correctly but I got that error while running.

Comment: Yep for some reason it only occurs with the `TkAgg` backend, not with the `Qt5Agg` backend. The other code from that answer works fine with both backends.

Comment: See [updated original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47676107/4124317) for a fix for `TkAgg`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks, now it works on my system. To modify it for my question above, can you please tell me what 'line.axes.figure' is? I don't have that in my code and I don't know how to modify your code so that I can use it for my code above. Because I have subplots, I cannot use 'line, = ax.plot([],[], lw=3)' in your code.

Comment: Use `axis[0,0].figure`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest wow, it works now. Thank you very much